# Orthogonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Say we have a number of vectors $h_1=(2,0)$, $h_2=(1,3)$ which are not orthogonal to each other.

There is a way to make them orthogonal with the help of this orthogonalisation formula:

Here I will use $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle$ to show the dot product of 2 vectors.

$\begin{align}
e_1 & = h_1 & = (2,0)
\\
e_2 & = h_2 - \frac{\langle h_2,e_1\rangle}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle} e_1.
\end{align}$

$e_2$ will be orthogonal to $e_1$.   So we can conclude that the  vector $h_2$ is corrected with the help of vector $e_1$ and the quotient ($\frac{\langle h_2,e_1\rangle}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}$).

So my question is:   Where does this quotient come from ($\frac{\langle h_2,e_1\rangle}{\langle e_1,e_1\rangle}$) ?

Comment: $\frac{\langle h_2, e_1 \rangle}{\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle} e_1$ is the projection of $h_2$ onto $e_1$. Given this, maybe drawing a diagram using vectors in the plane will help you understand the complete formula for $e_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{\langle\, h_2,e_1\,\rangle}{\langle\, e_1,e_1\,\rangle}e_1$ is the orthogonal projection of $h_2$ onto the line directed by $e_1$. When you substract from a vector its orthogonal projection onto the line directed by $e_1$, you get a vector orthogonal to $e_1$ (make a sketch!).